# Making an N-by-N grid

Tags: python, grid

I need to do the following but am stuck:

Get an integer N from the user
Print an N-by-N grid of one-digit numbers
The digit in the ith row, jth column should be the last digit of i×j

```
Type an integer: 12

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4
3 6 9 2 5 8 1 4 7 0 3 6
4 8 2 6 0 4 8 2 6 0 4 8
5 0 5 0 5 0 5 0 5 0 5 0
6 2 8 4 0 6 2 8 4 0 6 2
7 4 1 8 5 2 9 6 3 0 7 4
8 6 4 2 0 8 6 4 2 0 8 6
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4
```

Comment: Hi @wootwoop. On StackOverflow you should post what you have attempted so far. This demonstrates that you have put in effort and helps people help you. If I don't know what you have tried, I cannot answer what is specifically blocking you.

Comment: `print(*([' '.join([str((stack*overflow)%10) for stack in range(1,N+1)]) for overflow in range(1,N+1)]), sep='\n')`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I like how you stuck that little advertisement in there.

Comment: @zondo: gotta stay entertained somehow, right? :P

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a bit of a homework problem.

You can initialize a NxN array (list of lists) by `array = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]` and end up with an array of zeros. Then setting the values of each entry depending on its position in the array should be simple enough.

Are you familiar with the `%` (modulus) operator? e.g. `15 % 10 -> 5` You can use it to get the last digit of a multi-digit number.

Edit: it can be easily done in a single line of Python, but you should make sure you understand the approach to the problem.

Comment: No, you can't do that actually.  `[0 for 0 in range(N)]` is assigning `0` to each number in `range(N)`.  You can not assign a literal to another value.  You are probably thinking of `_`, which is the commonly used name for variables that will not be used.

Comment: i edited it, and you caught the error before i made the change. sorry